# MySQL Quiz with multi choice and users select questions that is not answered

Tags: mysql, sql

please help.
I have three tables.
I want to select question that does not answered by user
this is my database structure

Questions table:

```
id, q_title, first_choice, second_choice, third_choice, right_answer
```

answers table :

```
 id, q_id, u_id, the_answer, isAnswered
```

users table :

```
    id, email, password, name, phone
```

I tried a lot of SQL statements but it doesn't worked as I want.
this one of my tries

```
SELECT questions.id,questions.q_title,answers.q_id,answers.u_id,users.id
FROM questions,
     answers,
     users
WHERE questions.id not in (SELECT answers.q_id from answers
                           WHERE users.id = answers.u_id)
  and users.id = 3
```

sample data for question table:

```
 id, q_title, first_choice, second_choice, third_choice, right_answer
 1      q1       f1               f2          f3            f2
 2      q2       f1               f2          f3            f1
 3      q3       f1               f2          f3            f3
```

sample data for answers table:

```
 id, q_id, u_id, the_answer, isAnswered
 1    1     3       f2        true
 2    3     2       f3        true
```

sample data for users table:

```
 id,      email,      password, name,   phone
  1    user@xxx.com     xp       x1     21564
  2    user2@xxx.com    xp       x2     56841
  3    user3@xxx.com    xp       x3     95682
```

now user with id 3 answered question one.
and there is three questions I want the questions that is not answered by user with id 3.

The expected result:

```
id,   q_title,  q_id,  u_id, id
1      q2        2      3    3
2      q3        3      3    3
```

hope it is clear.

Comment: Tip of today: Switch to modern, explicit `JOIN` syntax. Easier to write (without errors), easier to read (and maintain), and easier to convert to outer join if needed.

Comment: Add some sample table data and the expected result - all as formatted text, not images.

Comment: @jarlh I have updated my question.

Comment: I can't see that you have included the expected result as requested by @jarlh. (You are familiar with the use case, we aren't, so you need to make it as easy as possible for the community to help you.)

Comment: @MandyShaw can you take a look?

Comment: I think I would start by redesigning the questions table

Comment: @Strawberry what is the appropriate design ?

Comment: Your sample dataset does not make sense. Shouldn't the value of `right_answer` be one of the `first_choice`, `second_choice` and `third_choice` values ?

Comment: @MadhurBhaiya you'r right I have updated my question with the right answers.

Comment: the problem is I cant get the questions that are not answered by for example user with id 3. it should be two questions (q2,q3) because  he already answered one question.(q1)

Comment: up up up please help

Answer (score -1):

The following should work, but to be sure, I'd need you to edit your question and add the schema (The **create table** statement) for each table, and some sample data that should produce a result.

```
SELECT 
    q1.id,
    q1.q_title,
    a1.q_id,
    u.id
FROM users u
LEFT JOIN answers a
    ON a.u_id = u.id
JOIN questions q
    ON a.q_id = q.id
LEFT JOIN answers a1
    ON a1.u_id <> u.id
JOIN questions q1
    ON a1.q_id = q1.id
WHERE a.id IS NULL
    AND (NOT a1.id IS NULL)
    AND u.id = 8
GROUP BY q1.id,
    q1.q_title,
    a1.q_id,
    u.id
```

---

**UPDATE:**

I worked a bit on your SQL Fiddle, and came up with a solution. I added another answer for the question user 8 had not answered.

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8316f/1)

**MySQL 5.6 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE `answers` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `q_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `u_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `the_answer` text CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
  `isAnswered` text CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;

--
-- Dumping data for table `answers`
--

INSERT INTO `answers` (`id`, `q_id`, `u_id`, `the_answer`, `isAnswered`) VALUES
(1, 1, 2, 'first_choice', 'true'),
(4, 1, 0, 'second_choice', 'true'),
(2, 7, 8, 'third_choice', 'true'),
(3, 9, 8, 'third_choice', 'true');


CREATE TABLE `questions` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `q_title` text NOT NULL,
  `first_choice` text NOT NULL,
  `second_choice` text NOT NULL,
  `third_choice` text NOT NULL,
  `right_answer` text NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

--
-- Dumping data for table `questions`
--

INSERT INTO `questions` (`id`, `q_title`, `first_choice`, `second_choice`, `third_choice`, `right_answer`) VALUES
(9, 'ما هي عاصمة فلسطين؟', 'القدس', 'بغداد', 'مكة', 'القدس'),
(10, 'ما هي عاصمة انجلترا؟', 'واشنطن', 'كييف', 'لندن', 'لندن'),
(1, 'ما هي سنة استغلال السودان؟', '1965', '1956', '1989', '1956'),
(7, 'ما هي عاصمة اليونان؟', 'اثينا', 'كييف', 'واشنطن', 'اثينا'),
(8, 'ما هي عاصمة السعودية؟', 'الرياض', 'عمان', 'القاهرة', 'الرياض');


CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(200) NOT NULL,
  `password` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  `name` mediumtext NOT NULL,
  `phone` varchar(15) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `email`, `password`, `name`, `phone`) VALUES
(3, 'ahmed.aau5@gmail.com', '$2y$10$AC8q.PFdZNWN23OqwKbryOoy/zkutJEtSSS0VXR8qUXaQuWflAle6', 'Ahmed Mohamed', '249117446667'),
(2, 'ahmed.aau4@gmail.com', '$2y$10$kM2RD8nDNdsegk5km5bAyOqatWj9F45YdaElxXUq9uiywa.zgwgO6', 'Ahmed Mohamed', '249901222620'),
(4, 'ahmed.juvg@vhjv.com', '$2y$10$oqnnymFr/BTTMUkYWAc9LuQ4RhsrBMohPOPlTFs5FiLJecJan2Cl.', 'Ahmed', '249117446667'),
(8, 'ahmed@gmail.com', '$2y$10$epia0tc3V4m1wlU4sqva7eV4fGq4ekzh2ZDb.tRP6VSA4WPxytyiG', 'Ahmed', '249901222620');
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT
    q1.id,
    q1.q_title,
    a1.id as `ans_id`,
    a1.the_answer,
    u1.id
FROM questions q1
LEFT JOIN
  (SELECT 
      q.id as questionid
  FROM users u
  LEFT JOIN answers a
      ON a.u_id = u.id  AND a.isAnswered = 'true'
  LEFT JOIN questions q
      ON a.q_id = q.id
  WHERE u.id = 8
  GROUP BY q.id) x1
  ON x1.questionid = q1.id
JOIN answers a1
  ON q1.id = a1.q_id
LEFT JOIN users u1
  ON u1.id = 8
WHERE x1.questionid IS NULL
GROUP BY
    q1.id,
    q1.q_title,
    a1.id,
    a1.the_answer,
    u1.id
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/8316f/1/0)**:

Questions that user 8 has not answered.

```
| id |                              q_title | ans_id |    the_answer | id |
|----|-------------------------------|--------|---------------|----|
|  1 | ما هي سنة استغلال السودان؟ |      1 |  first_choice |  8 |
|  1 | ما هي سنة استغلال السودان؟ |      4 | second_choice |  8 |
```

Comment: What part in your question that you updated applies to this answer?

Comment: Did you try this statement?

Comment: #1054 - Unknown column 'users.id' in 'on clause'

Comment: Check the updated statement. The ```users``` table was aliased to ```u```

Comment: The left join a1 join condition has no a1 reference - correct?

Comment: Oops! I'll fix that.

Comment: it has an error: #1055 - Expression #4 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'platform.a1.u_id' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by

Comment: Just fixed the one pointed out by @jarlh. If you get an error, show the whole error. It can help find where the problem is.

Comment: Not a common configuration. Just add the columns in the SELECT clause to the GROUP BY statement

Comment: I removed the answer.u_id since for the questions you are looking for will not have any answers for the selected user.

Comment: Can you create a SQL Fiddle with some sample data? Then post a link to it here.

Comment: @SloanThrasher yes sure I am trying to create db schema

Comment: @SloanThrasher please take a look here : http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/6dc7017/1

Comment: See if the update in my answer meets your requirements,.